# Graphing measurements with uncertainties

Tags: measurements, data-analysis, visualization

I need to draw a graph of measurements of time for a ball to drop on an inclined plane, with error bars, along with lines of best and worst fit. The problem is that I need to do this on the computer and I am unsure about what graphing package I can use to do this and how to go about doing it. I have access to Wolfram Mathematica 7, but I'm unsure about graphing points with uncertainties.

Comment: I'm not sure that this a great topic for Physics.SE (might be better on Super User as it is a question about the choice of software tools), and I am certain that if we are going to keep it it should be CW like the book resources. Thoughts from the commentariat?

Comment: *Aside:* "worst fit"?!? Perhaps you mean the limits in which the fit is reasonable.

Comment: @dmckee, Yes by worst fit I meant the most extreme lines that still satisfy the uncertainties, i.e. pass through the error bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In particle physics the core tool for this purpose these days is [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) (a few years back there were still a significant number of people using [PAW](http://paw.web.cern.ch/paw/) (part of [CERNLIB](http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/))). Both of these choices suffer somewhat from being big, heavy tools to install just to get some graphing done---we use them because they are primarily the environments in which we did analysis.

A lighter and less specific (but still surprisingly capable) tool is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

I've also [seen a lot of activity on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scipy]+plot) from people using python based tools like [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) for plotting. ROOT also provides [python bindings](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/howtos#python).

Comment: I whole heartedly second dmckee's answer here.  I've not heard of Root before (thanks for giving me the heads up) but I use scipy quite regularly.  If you don't want to have to deal with installing software, I recommend using sagemath's notebook server.  You can use any scipy/matplotlib stuff there for free (http://www.sagemath.org/).